# R Barplot with one bar - how to plot correctly

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want to plot a regular bar plot in R, but with just one bar. What I don't like is the fact that the bar width gets to be the width of the whole plot. I want the bar to be "thinner", but I don't know how to do it.

Default command is:

```
barplot(percentage, col=c("brown4"))
```

where percentage is a fraction. I tried using xlim parameter, but it gets very messy (bar goes completely to the right or left). For example, I tried:

```
barplot(percentage, col=c("brown4"), xlim=c(0.5,1))
```

but this stretches the bar even more. I am an R noob.

Comment: is this a stacked bar?

Comment: @user2510479 No it's not. Just an ordinary bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to play around with the width of the device you plotting to. E.g.:

```
# plot to a Windows graphic device
windows(height = 10, width = 4)
barplot(0.5)

# plot to PDF
pdf(height = 10, width = 2)
barplot(0.5)
dev.off()
```

You may also try `width` together with `xlim`

```
barplot(0.5, width = 0.1, xlim = c(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `width` argument to `barplot` says:

> `width` optional vector of bar widths. Re-cycled to length the number of bars drawn. Specifying a single value will have no visible effect unless `xlim` is specified.

So specify both `width` and `xlim`. The interaction of these two is not obvious (to me) so you will probably need to play around with them until they look like you want them to.

```
percentage <- 0.25
barplot(percentage, width=0.2, xlim=c(0,1.2), col="brown4")
```

[image]